# How to configure grails-spring-security-saml plugin version 5.0.0-RC3 for https applications

Tags: grails, saml-2.0, grails-plugin, spring-saml

I am upgrading my Grails4 application to Grails5 and am trying to upgrade the grails-spring-security-saml plugin from version 4.0.2 to version 5.0.0-RC3.

I am using Okta as my identity provider and if my app is http, I can successfully authenticate. If my app is https (behind a reverse proxy), the Okta response is denied because the audience, etc, doesn't match (http vs https).

I believe I got this working on the earlier (4.0.2) version by replacing

```
contextProvider(SAMLContextProviderImpl)
```

with

```
contextProvider(SAMLContextProviderLB) {
    scheme = conf.saml.scheme
    serverName = conf.saml.serverName
    serverPort = conf.saml.serverPort
    contextPath = conf.saml.contextPath
    includeServerPortInRequestURL = conf.saml.includeServerPortInRequestURL
}
```

I am unsure of what needs to be done for this version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing two things:

1. added the following to application.groovy: server.forwardHeadersStrategy = "framework"
2. in my tomcat/server.xml file I added the following to the Connector port configuration: scheme="https"

Comment: How did you get the contextProvider to work, because If I have what you have I get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager' on that. I've tried to figure out how to wire MetadataManager, but for me that has just led to pain and sufferering.

Comment: @virtualdogbert The 5.0.0-RC3 plugin doesn't have contextProvider. So it was something I configured in 4.0.2 but not in the 5.0.0 version.